# How to get "substring" from a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, c99

I have a char array that is of the form:

[17 chars, a tab char, 17 chars, a tab char, 17 chars, a tab char, a char representing a number between 1 and 4 digits long, null-byte]

I want to store the chars that sit between the tab char and the null-byte in a new variable.

EXAMPLE 1: This could be my char Array:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,3,4,\0]

And I would want to save the int 34 in a variable called x.

EXAMPLE 2: This could be my char Array:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\t,5,9,9,\0]

And I would want to save the int 599 in a variable called x.

I can do this easily if I know the number of digits of that number, but am not sure how to solve the problem of having a number of unknown length.

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Look up `memcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks, but from reading the documentation for memcpy(), it seems that 
you can't choose a starting index other than 0 (i.e. you can only get the first n chars of the string), rather than n chars between index a and index b.

Comment: Sure you can, via pointer arithmetic. Just add `a` to the pointer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your string (aka `char` array) is pointed to by `str`, since you seem to need that number in an `int` then you can use `atoi(str + 3 * (17 + 1))` to get what you want.

If you want that in another string then you can use `strcpy(str2, str + 3 * (17 + 1))` assuming that your buffer is pointed to by `str2`.

btw, you need to include `stdlib.h` for `atoi()` and `string.h` for `strcpy()`.